# Ensuring compatibility of transpiled TypeScript code with older browsers

Tags: typescript, browser

I'm using TypeScript for my web application development and transpiling my code to JavaScript using the TypeScript compiler. I'm targeting an older ECMAScript version for compatibility with older browsers. If I use newer JavaScript features in my TypeScript code, will the transpiled code work in older browsers that don't support those features?

Do I need to take any additional steps to ensure compatibility? Thanks!

Comment: How old are the browsers you need to support? IE11? IE5?

Comment: As asked this question is quite broad and risks being closed as needing more details or clarity.  Could you [edit] to specify which ECMAScript version you're targeting and which newer JavaScript features you're talking about?